# Optimal Manufacturing Process for a Device

Tags: semiconductor

I am designing a device that has tiny etched gratings (shown in red) in the silicon substrate, with various structures on either side of it (shown in green). I am wondering what the ideal way would be to manufacture such a device. Should I:

- Manufacture the gratings first and then the green structures, using resists to protect the grating. However, there is a chance of contamination from the other manufacturing process.
- Manufacture the green structures first and then the gratings at the end, thus avoiding exposure of the gratings to contamination due to their small size.

[image]

Comment: Let us know if you want us to migrate this to Engineering.SE or ElectricalEngineering.SE!

Comment: Sadly this question has now reached the 60-day limit for migration to Engineering.SE, where you might have had a better chance at getting this answered, but your one question on Engineering.SE was "abandoned" in that you didn't answer the question that someone asked you in a comment, so I don't think there's much chance of you getting an answer there (or here) unless you become more responsive to people's comments.